# What do I do with extra Enchantments in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I am playing Neverwinter again on the XBox after taking a few years off. I have Enchantments on all of my equipment slots, everything is at least level 5. I understand the refining process, and have been refining along the way. But now I have a number of Enchantments that are level 2 through 6, and I don't need them. I understand my choices to be:

1. Sell them to a Vendor for a few silver.
2. Sell them at auction for maybe a couple hundred Astral Diamonds (if they aren't bound).
3. Donate to Guild coffers (if they aren't bound).
4. Convert them to Refinement Points at like 50 RP each.

I know the earlier version of Refining let you combine lower Enchantments into higher ones, that is what all the older videos online show. But I don't think that's an option anymore. So, just convert to RP is all I can do with them?

Answer (score 0):

Anything above Rank 12 can be traded at the Antiquities Scholar vendor for special tokens you can use to buy the new enchantments.

Anything under Rank 12, save them for a 2x Refinement Points even and convert them to RP. Trust me you'll need them eventually.